# Mysql table structure

Tags: mysql, table

I will have a "clients" table and a "users" table what i wanna do is restrict access to some clients for some users

My question is how should i do the table structure for this? One solution comes to my mind is defining a field in clients table and putting the user ids in that field who wont have access to that client (so i can use that ids to check/exclude from result) but i dont know if it is efficent way? I mean if i do such field i am thinking to define it as "blob" field as i wont know how long that field should be, but i have concerns using a blob field/putting ids in one field? Will query be slow?

Is there a better/common way? Or my way is completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suitable solution is to create third table to link users with clients and so give access:

```
users             lnk_user_client_access                
-----             ----------------------                clients   
id_user --------- id_user                              --------
...               id_client   ------------------------ id_client
                                                       ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but isnt this going to cause multiple records for same id (for example i have 10.000 clients and 100 users then there will be 100.000 records in the third table?) and when i query/list the records of clients i will have to include the third table and this will cause a slow query?

Comment: with indexes performance is managed beside a client could be accessed by multiple users so a field in the client table wouldn't be a solution. (i had the same situation with more than 24Millions rows works fine)

Comment: @user120047 has the right solution - you need an association table to resolve many to many relationships.  If you join properly and there are no duplicate identifying values in users & clients, the number of rows projected will be the same as the linking table.  The added benefit is you can add additional columns to describe the user/client association.

Comment: Hi RMathis, you mean yassine has the right solution? a 3th table will be holding cilent ids for every user? Did i get it right? And then i will be processing by joining clients and users on the 3th table for queries?

Comment: @YassineLAADIDI thanks yassine i will be proceeding using your suggestion